# Retag django-notifcation as django-notification

Tags: support, retag-request

Please could a mod fix the spelling for the [django-notifcation](/questions/tagged/django-notifcation) tag.

It should be [django-notification](/questions/tagged/django-notification).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As there were only 8 questions with the incorrect tag I've gone ahead and retagged them all.